# arm renesas toolchain linker error

Tags: c, gcc, build, linker, arm

I am trying to build a project with arm renesas rz toolchain.

While building..,

Compiling is going fine.

But, at the linking stage...

arm-rz-eabi-ld: cannot find ./**comon**/src/riic/riic_driver/riic.o: No such file or directory

this error occured.

actually, the directory is ./***common***/src/riic/riic_driver/riic.o

but it is removing only 1 character from that and giving this error.

can anyone please help with resolving this error...!

Comment: Post the command line being used for linking

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple lines in your preprocessor include directories. Make sure the C/C++ Compiler Preprocessor settings have been set to the correct directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have multiple lines in preprocessor include directories and all the paths are fine. no mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was the depth of directories creating the problem.

My project contains more than 10 directories in the path starting from C:/.../....

I tried by placing all the c source files in only 1 directory instead of multiple.

It solved the problem.